# Execute a command multiple times using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

In Dapper we have [execute a command multiple times](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#execute-a-command-multiple-times) title that allow us to run query many time with different values. Is this possible in EF Core using `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` function as well?

Something like this:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(myStringQuery, myParameters)
```

and this code should translate following query:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn)
VALUES (@p0, @p2)
```

Currently this method does work, but only adding first index of my list (first parameter only) and generate below query:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn)
VALUES (@p0)
```

My string query look like:

```
StringBuilder myStringQuery = new();
sb.AppendLine("query ... VALUES ({0})")
```

I have to [solve problem in this](https://github.com/amirhosseini01/dotnet-samples/blob/main/NpgsqlAPI/Services/Blogs/BlogEFRawQueryServices.cs) way for now

```
StringBuilder sb = new();
sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO \"Blogs\"");
sb.AppendLine($"(\"{nameof(Blog.Url)}\")");
sb.AppendLine("VALUES");
int i;

for (i = 0; i < obj.Length - 1; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("({{{0}}}),", i);
}

sb.AppendFormat("({{{0}}})", i++);
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sb.ToString(), obj.Select(x => x.Url!));
```

but I want to solve this like in the Dapper version seen in [this link](https://github.com/amirhosseini01/dotnet-samples/blob/main/NpgsqlAPI/Services/Blogs/BlogDapperServices.cs)

Comment: Obviously EF Core has no similar functionality, not sure what are you looking for. If you want Dapper way, then use Dapper (if you don't know Dapper and EF Core can be used together).  EF Core in general is not oriented for executing raw SQLs, so it never will have same capabilities as SQL oriented libraries like Dapper. Not to mention that in EF Core the same operation is achieved w/o the need of raw SQL with simple `AddRange` and `SaveChanges`, which generates the necessary batching `INSERT` command(s).

Answer (score 3):

[EF-Core supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating) `Commands Batching`:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
   @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Demo.Batching;Trusted_Connection=True;",
   options => options.MaxBatchSize(1)
);
```

Its default value is `1000` which means it sends a batch of 1000 `insert/update/delete`s at once. Each batch should have `2100` parameters. More than that will be sent in a different batch.

Comment: This works only with EF Core generated commands inside `SaveChanges`. Which OP should have used. But for their concrete question regarding *raw SQL* commands, this has no effect, hence does not answer it.

Comment: He shouldn't use raw sql commands when there's a better way here.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it manually.

Let's say there is an entity:

```
public class Test
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There is a collection of parameters:

```
var myParameters = Enumerable.Range(1, 3)
    .Select(x => new object[] { Guid.NewGuid(), "name" + x });
```

Go through this collection in a loop and execute a query to the database:

```
foreach (var item in myParameters)
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("insert into Tests values ({0},{1})", item);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, im already implement this query using StringBuilder and it exist in my github that i mention in my post. im understand what you mean but im  looking for a way that work exactly like dapper. plus your solution run separate query each time that is not have good performance for lots of data